# No cache in sequence

Tags: oracle10g

Could you please help me in the below scenerio

In our application we are using the sequence with no cache. Even though sequence number is not generating with the order. It is resulting with gap in the sequence genearation.Below is the sequence definition.

SEQUENCE_OWNER SEQUENCE_NAME MIN_VALUE MAX_VALUE INCREMENT_BY C O  CACHE_SIZE LAST_NUMBER

DBOWNER SEQUENCENAME  1 1.00000000000000E+27 1 N N  0 145095

How could we achieve sequence number without gap.

Thanks,
Gajendra

Answer (score 2):

Sequence-generated numbers are not designed to be gap-free.

For example, use of a sequence number followed by a rollback will not rollback the use of the sequence number.

If you really do need a gap free number then you'll have to sacrifice concurrency by implementing a locking mechanism while you generate a new number and commit the new row.

Alternatively, if you need high-concurrency, you can leave the value blank and fill it in asynchronously with a batch process.